# JAXB mapping XML document to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cxf, wadl

I am trying to make a simple client sample for a REST service.
The server can send the response both in XML and JSON. I can not change the behaviour of the server.

I made the declaration of my element:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="ServerInformation">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="version" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="zone" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:dateTime" />
        <xsd:element name="timeout" type="xsd:int" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I have a problem with only the "type" field. When the server answer with a JSON response, I have a "type" : "server_information" node. So the mapping is correctly made into Java. I can call the method foo.getType() and it returns "server_information". It is the expected behaviour.

I want to do the same when the server answer with an XML response. The problem is I don't have node named "type". the type value is contained into the root node of the XML answer.
Here the XML answer:

```
<server_information>
      <name>Server Name</name>
      <version>[development build]</version>
      <zone>Europe/Paris</zone>
      <date>2015-02-18T16:15:35.892Z</date>
      <timeout>300</timeout>
</server_information>
```

I don't have any problem with the mapping of the others elements (name, version, zone...). Only with type.

So my question is, how I can specify to JAXB to get the name of the root node ("server_information") into the "type" element ?
I think it should be done with the binding file (serverInformation.xjb) but I have no idea how to do that...

I also need to be compatible with both JSON and XML. So in JSON, I still can use the "type" node.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same JAXB objects for XML and JSON?

Comment: I can use separate files for the WADL description if needed, but in Java I want only one object with all the fields. The JSON object is already correct, I juste need to be able to get the root name of the XML file and put it into the field "type".

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's worth the effort. I would pick either JSON or XML and stick to that. If you're making a client *sample*, just make one of both types. Does the server respect the `Accept:` header?

Comment: Yes the server accept the "Accept" header. My current project is just a sample, but I will have to implement a real client after that will have to be able to choose the format (XML or JSON).

Comment: Yeah, so I suggest creating real client that just uses your preferred format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by deleting the "type" field in my xsd file and by adding a Java annotation containing the XML root element.

I can now get the type using the value of this annotation. All my entities extends an abstract class with the "getType()" method.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "server_information")
public class ServerInformation extends AbstractEntityBase
{...}
```

Abstract class for each entity:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntityBase{

public final String getType(){
    return getClass().getAnnotation(XmlRootElement.class).name();
}
```

}

xsd file:

```
    <xsd:complexType name="server_information">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="version" type="xsd:string" />
        <.../>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

xsd bindings file:

```
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="ServerInformation.xsd" node="/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[1]">

    <annox:annotate target="class">
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name = "server_information")
    </annox:annotate>

    <annox:annotate target="class">
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, value = {"type"})
    </annox:annotate>

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:superClass name="com.foo.AbstractEntityBase" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```